British Sci fi movie time travel kidnaping occult?
British movie 1980's  to 90's. Color.
It is about 2( 1?) boys some maybe kidnappers, the occult, a creepy 1940's black vintage flying car that has metal wings that pop out. It is like a rolls Royce style car. Takes place in England. There is a running and hiding scene in the English country-side.
There is a metal bed that also flies or time travels/ teleports. There I think is a room with a masonic occult looking stone at one point. Some of the adults have magic? 
It was a very dull rainy shot movie.
At one point the magic bed is in the woods.
At the beginning the boy or boys are kidnapped by a man in a 3 piece suit and bowler hat and a creepy lady in black clothes.
I could be mixing up/ combining a few movies? not sure
This was on cable TV in Virginia in the late 80's - early 90s. like 86-93 ish? It's driving me crazy for years not knowing what this is called or being able to see all of it.
It is not Bedknobs and Broomsticks. This is a darker lit, and darker brooding movie.

Some elements sound like the film Chitty Chiity Bang Bang, based on the book written by James Bond author Ian Fleming. A flying vintage car, the Child Catcher etc. But other things do not perhaps you are correct and are mixing up more than one film.http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0062803/

Could it be The Box of Delights?

I also think that your description is somewhat similar  to The Box of Delights (1984) a six episode British miniseries, based on the 1935 novel by John Masefield and set in that period.  
see here:
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086675/1
The box of delights has magical powers and the protagonist can fly, change size, etc., when he has possession of it.
I remember a scene where Cole Hawlings (Patrick Troughton) explains to someone the story of the Box of Delights.  But all I remember is that it involved Raymond Lully (c. 1232-1316).
The villains use at least one flying automobile.
Besides getting the Box of delights, their plan involved ruining Christmas mass at the local cathedral.
That is all I remember, I hope that is enough to help you decide if it is the one you are looking form.

YES ! thank you so much. It was Box of Delights. Finally, I can watch it entirely. I never caught it all at once on television. Thank you very much. I've been asking in forums for years. Good work. The story line has run unresolved in my head since the 80's .
